# Seamlessly connect two anchors

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This is the work in question. How can I seamlessly connect the two anchors on my vector drawing (the gap is highlighted with a red circle - that's not part of the vector). The picture on the right is a reference drawing.

Btw, I'm using Illustrator.

[image: Work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Direct Selection Tool**
2. Select two points with **SHIFT** key
3. **Connect selected end points**
   [image]

---

And there is better way to draw your vector:
[image]